# WCF Service in Sharepoint 2010 can't find my Custom ServiceHostFactory class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I made a great WCF service in my dev environment, then when I pushed it up to production I got various errors saying "This collection already contains an address with scheme http..."

So, I created a Custom ServiceHostFactory class for my service.

Now when I upload it I get:

The CLR Type 'WCFServices.MultipleHostFactory' could not be loaded during
service compilation. Verify that this type is either defined in a source
file located in the application's \App_Code directory, contained in a
compiled assembly located in the application's \bin directory, or present in
an assembly installed in the Global Assembly Cache. Note that the type name
is case-sensitive and that the directories such as \App_Code and \bin must
be located in the application's root directory and cannot be nested in
subdirectories.

I checked the GAC and my assembly is indeed there.

Can anyone explain why this error is occuring?

Again, I am using .NET 3.5 on Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Did you reference your factory type using the full assembly-qualified name? Can you post the contents of your svc file?

Comment: Yes. I did.
<%@ ServiceHost Debug="true" Language="C#" 
Service="WCFServices.MyServices, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" Factory="WCFServices.MultipleHostFactory" CodeBehind="MyServices.cs" %>

Answer (score 0):

Is it "WCFServices.MultipleHostFactory" or "WCFServices.MultipleHostsFactory"?  If its the first, thats why because that namespace does not match that you said in your question.

Comment: No its Host.

When I run the Debug out of VS 2010 it goes to the Sharepoint site then errors out in the MultipleHostFactory class due to a null value in the Uri[] baseaddresses.

This value becomes null no matter what I do too. I've binded it to an address myself right in the createServiceHost override, but still becomes null. I think it is due to the debugger, though. On the actual site I get the error mentioned above.

I think the two errors connect with each other in some way but I can't yet see how.

Comment: There are descrepencies in the error and the .svc Service tag due to my hand typing this post. sorry about that I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was able to remove one of the bindings from the application host configuration file. After talking with the administrator, I found that he had two bindings for port 80. One was IP:80:[DNS name] and the other was :80:

We agreed to get rid of the :80: binding and the WCF service was able to deploy to SP.

If anyone ever runs into that CLR loading issue, please post with a solution. I still don't have a good explanation for that problem.